# feign.RetryableException: Connection reset executing GET

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

We have a micro services architecture deployed on AWS ECS with Docker. The API Gateway and Eureka is from Spring. We have Java/NodeJS micro services which are working perfectly through the gateway but the .NET micro service, which uses SteelToe Eureka client gives us connection reset exception.

The following are screenshots for a better understanding.

[Eureka app registration details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIGEn.png)

[Feign client stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaa4E.png)

We have spent a lot of time, trying to figure it out, but at the moment with no success. Can we get some help on this to solve it please.

Thank you very much!

Comment: any luck? Are you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time has passed since the question, but my solution maybe will help someone. I faced `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` during calling FeignClient. To fix it i change used OpenJDK to Oracle JDK and exception was gone! So, i really don't know root of the problem, but changing jdk works for me.